# MySQL Console Returning an Arrow for a perfectly simple upload procedure

Tags: mysql, console

I'm sure I will attract a lot of haters for this simple question but I've been pushed into a corner and I genuinely need help.

So, I'm about to embark on uploading thousands of large CSV files to my local database and I am honestly using a piece of code I used last time around and it worked. And I can't figure out why it suddenly stopped working.

When I press Enter, the command doesn't execute, it gives me an arrow symbol suggesting that it expects more but I don't have anything else to give it. Why???

Yes, I have tried this command both as multi-line command and as single-line. Makes no difference. No error messages, it's just expecting more.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/acme_cp85238_85238.esw3cal_S.202304030000-0100-0' INTO TABLE server_logs FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Comment: Mysql won't think the statement has been fully entered until it is terminated with a semi colon- you don't appear to be doing so